# HTTP verbs PUT and DELETE stopped working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-verbs, iis-10

I have a ASP.NET Web API project where I use `PUT` and `DELETE` frequently. Sometime during the last couple of months `PUT` and `DELETE` stopped working. The web.config is still the same and the verbs **works fine on my other machine**.

I haven't worked with the project during this time. The only things I recall I have done is the Windows 10 anniversary update and a couple of Visual Studio updates, but I have done the same updates on my other machine.

During this time my WCF services stopped working too. In attempts to get them to work I reinstalled some Windows components. I have installed everything that has to do with IIS.

Can this verb problem have anything to do with missing Windows components? I have no idea what it can be.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I managed to install support for WebDav publishing when I reinstalled the Windows features for IIS. I removed it and got my `PUT` and `DELETE` back!